# Drag and drop into from browser to FineUploader

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I've been using FineUploader to upload images onto my website but I'm finding that a lot of people are trying to drag images from other websites into the uploader. I know other websites (ie: pinterest) grab data from that. Has anybody had success grabbing that browser image using FineUploader?

Comment: What specific issue are you seeing? Are you not able to do this? Which browsers?

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to do it. I don't know if it's a feature or if it's something I'm going to have to customize pretty heavily. I was hoping I could find somebody that's done it to just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to enable the ["paste to upload" feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/paste-to-upload.html). That is supported in Chrome/Opera. You can then copy the image and then paste it into Fine Uploader.

Setup:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
   paste: {
      targetElement: document
   }
})
```